# How to stop elements from obscuring each other when zooming into browser

Tags: html

I won't bother to paste my code here since the question is pretty general.

It's easy to just make a bunch of divs with borders/backgrounds, position them in different ways and see how they spill into each other when you zoom in. I'm using Chrome, and the default zoom method is ctrl + to zoom in and ctrl - to zoom out.

When I do this, a pretty layout turns into a disaster. Notably, this happens a lot with position: absolute. What are some responsive design techniques one can use to avoid this behavior and ensure that their site looks good at any zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `flexbox` is the best technique to avoid this problems

Answer (score 1):

You should create a css file witch will load when the screen width gets bellow 800px.
The css file should contain the mobile css code.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)">
```

Here some great tips what is important for mobile layout: https://www.hostgator.com/blog/how-make-website-mobile-friendly/

Answer (score 0):

One can also consider percentages or em or rem or vh as units for sizing and spacing. Barring that its also great time to learn a styling and gridding system (bootstrap, tailwind-css, material-ui, etc)

But learning display: flex is huge.